# Recursive query within recursive query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to solve a problem consisting of 2 recursions.
In one of the 2 recursions I find out the answer to one question which is "What is the leaf member of a specific input (template)?" This is already solved.

In a second recursion I would like to run this query for a number of other inputs (templates).

1st part of the problem:

I have a tree and would like to find the leaf of it. This part of the recursion can be solved using this query:

```
with recursive full_tree as (
  select id, "previousVersionId", 1 as level
    from template
  where
    template."id" = '5084520a-bb07-49e8-b111-3ea8182dc99f'
  union all 
    select c.id, c."previousVersionId", p.level + 1
    from template c
    inner join full_tree p on c."previousVersionId" = p.id
)
select * from full_tree
order by level desc
limit 1
```

The query output is one record including the leaf id I'm interested in. This is fine.

2nd part of the query:

Here's the problem. I would like to run the first query n times.
Currently I can run the query only if it's just one id ('5084520a-bb07-49e8-b111-3ea8182dc99f' in the example). But what If I have a list of 100 such ids.
My ultimate goal is to get one id response (the leaf id) to each of the 100 template ids in the list.
In theory, a query that allows me to run above query for each of my e.g. 100 template ids would solve my problem.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  I would advise you to set up a db fiddle of some sort.

Comment: seems like you could use an IN statement in the WHERE clause, i.e. `where template."id" in  ('1', '2', '3', '4'). Don't know if the inner join full_tree will get tricky, but you'd definitely need to ad `template."id"` to your JOIN clause somehow.